# Family Tree, method confusion

Tags: java, class, methods, parameters, tree

I am currently working on a project that involves creating a program that can input and display a person's family tree. However, after creating a class called Person with a constructor to set up the name of that person and a method to call that class, I am realizing that I do not know how to input the proper parameters for the method that calls the 'person' class. Here is my code below-

```
public class FamilyTree

{
    private class Person
    {
        private String name;

        public Person(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;

        }
    }
public void InputInformationfor(Person person)
{
//also do not know what would go here
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    FamilyTree famtree = new FamilyTree();
    famtree.InputInformationfor(??????);

}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm truly trying to push my understanding of the mechanics and bare essentials of java, as this is where my ambitions in coding are surely halted.

P.S. Not sure why stackOverflow is formatting the first few lines of my code as normal text...

Comment: It would be best for you to read some OOP (object oriented programming) books in order to understand the meaning and the right way to use classes and objects. If you don't have enough time to do that, maybe search for an online course or some tutorial.

Comment: I surely will. As a college student, sometimes just the here and now is top on my priority list, but I plan on squeezing in time whenever I can to master the basics. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't need a private class you can define classes as follows,

```
public class FamilyTree {
//....
}
class Person {
//....
}
```

In FamilyTree class, you need to have a structure to store people. Although FamilyTree is a *tree*, you can use a *list* just for simplicity. You should define this list and initialize it in the constructor.

```
public class FamilyTree {
    List<Person> personList;
    public FamilyTree(){
        personList = new ArrayList();
    }
    //...
}
```

When you want to add a person to personList, you can call InputInformationfor method. However, this is a bad name imo, you can say addPerson.

```
public void addPerson(Person person){
    personList.add(person);
}
```

Finally, in main method, you can create a person first, then add it to the list. So, final code looks like this,

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class FamilyTree {
    List<Person> personList;
    public FamilyTree(){
        personList = new ArrayList();
    }

    public void addPerson(Person person){
        personList.add(person);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        FamilyTree famtree = new FamilyTree();
        Person person = new Person("Emre");
        famtree.addPerson(person);
    }
}

class Person {
    private String name;

    public Person(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. So in other words, calling a method that has a class as a parameter requires creating an instance of that class, i.e. 'person' or 'person1'?

Comment: Yes you can also do this in one line.
famtree.addPerson(new Person("Emre"));

Comment: Oh, even better. Truly appreciate it, Emre.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use something like this:
1. Define variables for the Person class and methods to add information for a person, for example:

```
public class Person {
      String name;
      String age;
      int age;
      String father;
      String mother;

//Define constructor
      public Person(){
      //What you want initialize.
      }

      public void setname(String nameinput){
      name = nameinput;
      }
}
```

2. Define how you want for a family tree, as you did for a person.
3. I would use a dummy Person class to add Persons to the family tree. So, in your main function you could add persons to the tree.

   ```
     public static void main(String[] args){
     Person dummy = new Person();
     //Add data to the person.
     dummy.setname("Mike");
     //Add the information you want to the dummy variable.
     //Then you can add the person to the tree.
     FamilyTree famtree = new FamilyTree();
     famtree.InputInformationfor(dummy);}
   ```

I hope this could help you. May be you must read must about classes. Java for dummies is a good start.

Comment: Thank you very much, your explanation cleared a lot up for me.